# How to use Sizmek

Tags: html, tracking, ads

I have been creating some html5 ads which all work ok. The ad provider I am using is asking me to create the tracking with sizmek. I have incorporated EBloader file and my code looks like this...

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/EBloader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function initEB(){
     if (!EB.isInitialized()) {
       EB.addEventListener(EBG.EventName.EB_INITIALIZED, startAdDS);
     }
     else {
       startAdDS();
     }
    }

    function startAdDS() {
      document.getElementById("banner").style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    function handleClickthroughButtonClick() {
      EB.clickthrough();
    }
   </script>
```

I have also done a console log to make sure everything work and it seems fine.

The problem is that the ad provider has told me there is code missing from the sizmek export but as I didn't use sizmek to create the ads I have just incorporated the code it appears things are missing.

My question is, how would you create sizmek ads and how can I make a standard html5 ad sizmek compliant?

This is vague I know but then it comes to dealing with sizmek I am basic at best.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually calling your `initEB` function? I think sizmek recommends that you attach a listener to the `window.onload` event.

Try adding `window.addEventListener('load', initEB);`

Other than that, ask them to specify what is missing? Usually clicktracking is all people want, but sizmek has a bunch of tracking features that you can call from within a creative.